# Swap chains for windows covering multiple monitors

Tags: rendering, directx

I'm currently developing multi-monitor DX11 app and I ran into a very specific problem. When creating a swap chain for a window, a window handle and a pointer to device object should be passed, both parameters are required to be non-NULL. But when a window covers two monitors connected to different devices, pointer to exactly what device should be passed? Or should I create swap chains for each monitor in order to perform rendering of window parts?

I'm aware that in windowed mode, DWM performs final merging of swap chains back buffers into the real back buffer of its very own swap chain. But I can't understand how to perform rendering to a window that can be dragged from monitor to another monitor and back.

On the other hand I do understand that swap chain buffers are located into device memory so device must be specified when creating a swap chain. Window handle is required too because rendering is performed to a window. The problem is that I can't understand what exactly device must be used in case of a window spanning two monitors and, if I should create swap chains for each monitor, should I merge rendering results from all swap chains?

Thank you!

Comment: A swapchain is always associated with 1 window and 1 device https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#create-a-swap-chain. You don't have to create 2 swapchains, but you must always be prepared to recreate the swapchain and sometimes the device in any case (device lost, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm aware that swap chain requires window and device for being created. I can't understand what exactly device must be passed in case window in windowed mode covers two monitors connected each to the separate device. Thus, one portion of window must be rendered with the first device and second portion with the second one. Is that right?

Comment: No, look at the bitmap here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#enumerating-adapters "window 3" spans two adapters. You will create the window on the left/top adapter.

Comment: I see, back buffers of windowed mode swap chains are not tied to a particular device because DWM needs to apply its own effects and render the resulting image to its back buffer. Thus, app's back buffers can be created even in system memory if needed. So probably exact device object is not important? Or it's really required to take the top left corner of the client area and use the device the (0; 0) belongs to? I didn't see this moment clarified by the article...

Answer (score 2):

In general, DWM makes it work. For your window you can create a swapchain on any device, and DWM will composite it. *However* it is possible there will be a performance drop when your window moves from a monitor connected to the adapter on which the windows' swapchain was created (most efficient) to a monitor connected to another adapter (less efficient, more copies).

Also, the window cannot go fullscreen on a monitor connected to an adapter different from the one on which the windows' swapchain was created.

Perhaps for maximum perfomance you need to have one device per adapter, and juggle your rendering from one the another depending on where the window sits. But I have no experience with that. (Also, those adapters may have very different performance profiles to the point that copying be less expensive than rendering on the slow adapter.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in fact I'm still trying to find a way to automatically reconfigure graphics system accordingly to H/W setup and S/W state to keep rendering/physics process in balance. So sometimes some stages migrate from one device to another and i suggest can bring in some troubles.

Comment: Perhaps you can have Device as one parameter of rendering one frame. But certainly there are resources you want to keep from frame to frame (e.g. textures, shaders)... Keep them duplicated? Tiled resources? Complex. :-)   [Don't know about physics accel, sorry.]

Comment: Not sure about textures but vertex/index buffers can be shared across multiple devices for e.g. evaluating shadow mapping stage, so I suggest that keeping duplicates is inevitable. It's really complex, you are right, but pros overwhelm cons in case of success...